# Проблемы с латиницей при расшифровки FromBase64

Tags: c#, шифрование, base64

Почему расшифровка не поддерживает латиницу? Пробовал разные методы добавления Encoding не помогло (

```
public static class BaseHelper
{
 public static void EncryptFile(string filename, string output)
 {
  if (File.Exists(filename))
  {
    string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(EncodingDef(File.ReadAllText(filename)));
    File.WriteAllText(output, b64);
  }
}

public static void DecryptFile(string filename, string output)
{
   if (File.Exists(filename))
   {
     byte[] bb = Convert.FromBase64String(filename);
     string save = EncodingUtf8(bb);
     File.WriteAllText(output, save);
   }
}

 private static byte[] EncodingDef(string file) => 
 Encoding.Default.GetBytes(file);
 private static string EncodingUtf8(byte[] file) => 
  Encoding.UTF8.GetString(file);
}
```

Использую так:

```
string filename = "1.txt";
BaseHelper.EncryptFile(filename, "1_enc.txt");
BaseHelper.DecryptFile("1_enc.txt", "1.dec.txt");
```

Ошибка следующего вида:

> Входные данные не являются действительной строкой Base-64, поскольку
>   содержат символ в кодировке, отличной от Base 64, больше двух символов
>   заполнения или недопустимый символ среди символов заполнения.

Comment: В методе `DecryptFile` используется `FromBase64String(filename)` - **чтение из файла забыто**.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, А что использовать за место `FromBase64String` ?

Comment: `Convert.FromBase64String(filename);` ==> `Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(filename));` ?

Comment: @tym32167, во теперь заработало =) но с кодировкой даже при `UTF8` проблемы. ����� - вот такая ерунда.

Comment: предлагаете угадать что у вас за проблемы?

Comment: @tym32167, Предлагаю помочь решить данную проблему раз и навсегда )

Comment: тогда `private static byte[] EncodingDef(string file) =>
Encoding.Default.GetBytes(file);` ===> `private static byte[] EncodingDef(string file) =>
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file);`

Comment: @tym32167, Я его и использовал, и разные пробовал ( все что было ) не помогло кириллица не читается после расшифровки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устроили тут ромашку: та кодировка, не та кодировка...

Читаем из файла плоский текст сразу в виде байтов, методом `ReadAllBytes`. Кодировка при этом значения **не имеет**.

А вот результат в виде строки base64 записываем в файл с выбранной **нами** кодировкой. Для экономии вполне подойдёт ASCII - она с гарантией перекрывает base64.

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(plainTextFileName));
File.WriteAllText(base64FileName, base64, encoding);
```

Где encoding:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.ASCII; // или любая другая
```

При чтении строки base64 используем **ту же самую** кодировку. Гадать не нужно: мы её **сами** назначили при записи, поэтому она нам известна при чтении.

Раскодированный плоский текст опять записываем в виде байтов. Не нужно ломать голову о выборе кодировки: она будет та же, которая была в исходном файле.

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(base64FileName, encoding));
File.WriteAllBytes(plainTextFileName, bytes);
```

Comment: Работает на отлично, спасибо будем знать =)

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд зашифровка и расшифровка должна проводиться в одной и той же кодировке.

Попробуйте вместо:

```
string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(EncodingDef(File.ReadAllText(filename)));
```

Использовать это:

```
string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(filename)));
```

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло, только что заменил и проверил.

Comment: @Luser Попробуйте изменить кодировку с Default на UFT8
private static byte[] EncodingDef(string file) =>
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file);

        private static string EncodingUtf8(byte[] file) =>
            Encoding.UTF8.GetString(file);`

Answer (score 1):

1. Фиксим чтение из файла
2. Меняем кодировку по умолчанию (которая не обязательно utf-8) на utf-8

Получаем рабочий код

```
public static class BaseHelper
{
    public static void EncryptFile(string filename, string output)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(EncodingDef(File.ReadAllText(filename)));
            File.WriteAllText(output, b64);
        }
    }

    public static void DecryptFile(string filename, string output)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            byte[] bb = Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(filename));           
            string save = EncodingUtf8(bb);
            File.WriteAllText(output, save);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] EncodingDef(string file) => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file);
    private static string EncodingUtf8(byte[] file) => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(file);
}
```

Comment: Хм, у Вас показывает Русские буквы ( кириллица ) после расшифровки? У меня по прежнему ромбики вида �����.

Comment: @Luser у меня все хорошо показывает. Вы может редактором не тем смотрите? Редактору вашему укажите кодировку utf-8 для декодированного файла

Comment: @Luser также убедитесь, что оригинальный файл тоже в нужной кодировке

Comment: Точно =) Изначальный файл был сохранён в кодировки `ANSI` сохранил в `UTF8`, теперь нормально показывает. Но вот возник ещё вопрос по данной теме, если изначально стоит другая кодировка то при шифрование нужно указывать именно её? и расшифровку уже в uf8 ?!

Comment: @Luser зачем спрашивать, если это можно просто тупо попробовать? :)

Comment: Именно пробую, но так же интересно узнать ваше мнение))

Comment: @Luser у меня ночь, мне лень для вас пробовать :)

Comment: @Luser будете проьбовать - не забудьте, что чтение из файла и запись в файл тоже требует указания кодировки

Comment: @Luser И всё же, по сути я был прав )) Зашифровывать и расшифровывать нужно в одной и той же кодировке...

Comment: @РамазанАлисханов ну это звучит логично, если между шифровками/расшифровками кодировку не менять, то что было зашифровано, то и будет расшифровано